# What is the difference between range-v3 views::drop and views::drop_exactly?

Tags: c++, range-v3

Can someone explain the difference between range-v3's view adaptors `drop` and `drop_exactly`?

One difference I've observed is that if the number of elements in the range that is piped to these views is less than the argument to the view adaptors, `drop` seems to do the right thing, while `drop_exactly` seems to invoke UB.

When the argument is less than the number of elements in the range that is piped to these views, they both seem to work the same:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

namespace rv = ranges::views;

int main() 
{    
    std::vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    for (int i : v | rv::drop(3))
        std::cout << i;                    // prints 45
    
    for (int i : v | rv::drop(7))
        std::cout << i;                    // prints nothing

    for (int i : v | rv::drop_exactly(3))
        std::cout << i;                    // prints 45
    
    for (int i : v | rv::drop_exactly(7))
        std::cout << i;                    // prints garbage and crashes
}
```

Here's the [code](https://godbolt.org/z/rrr341).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/doc/index.md) for **`drop_exactly`**:

> Given a source range and an integral count, return a range consisting
> of all but the first *count* elements from the source range. **The
> source range must have at least that many elements.**

While the documentation for **`drop`** states:

> Given a source range and an integral count, return a range consisting
> of all but the first *count* elements from the source range, **or an
> empty range if it has fewer elements**.

<sup>emphasis added</sup>

---

I'm *guessing* that `drop_exactly` avoids bounds checks and therefore has the potential to be slightly more performant at the cost of maybe running past the `end` of the piped-in container, while `drop` apparently performs bounds checks to make sure you don't.

This is consistent with what you see. If you print stuff from `begin()+7` up to `begin()+5` (aka `end()`) of a `std::vector`, and the abort condition is implemented with `!=` instead of `<`, then you will continue to print the junk data that sits in the space allocated by the vector until at some point you run over the allocated chunk and the operating system steps in and segfaults your binary.

So, if you *know* the container to have as many entries as you wish to drop use the faster `drop_exactly`, otherwise use `drop`.

Comment: Yes, the documentation explains why the UB happens. And bounds checking for performance seems to be a plausible explanation for the difference. I'll wait and see if someone knows the answer, or figures it out from the implementation.

Comment: @cigien To be needlessly language-lawyery, the reason you are seeing UB is because the documentation of the library you are using says so. Piping in a shorter source range is specifically forbidden. :)